# Issue converting local time to UTC

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have tried below code to convert the local date-time to a UTC date-time. But they are coming as same. I think I am missing something here. Can anyone please help me how can I get the UTC date time from local datetime `10/15/2013 09:00 AM GMT+05:30`. This date time string I get from a outer system so if needed I can change the format.

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatInUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aaa z");
String startDateTime = "10/15/2013 09:00 AM GMT+05:30";
Date utcDate = outputFormatInUTC.parse(startDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ISO 8601 Format

Yes, if you can change the format of the string, you should. An international standard exists for this very purpose: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Like this `2013-12-26T21:19:39+00:00` or this `2013-12-26T21:19Z`.

### Joda-Time

Avoid using java.util.Date/Calendar classes. They are notoriously bad. Java 8 supplants them with new java.time.* JSR 310 classes. In the meantime, you can use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library which inspired JSR 310.

My example code below uses Joda-Time 2.3 running in Java 7 on a Mac.

### Example Code

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String string = "10/15/2013 09:00 AM GMT+05:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aaa zZ" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( string );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-10-15T03:30:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `TimeZone`:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatInUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aaa z");
String startDateTime = "10/15/2013 09:00 AM GMT+05:30";
outputFormatInUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
Date utcDate = outputFormatInUTC.parse(startDateTime);
String timeInUTC = outputFormatInUTC.format(utcDate);
System.out.println(timeInUTC);
```

Output:

```
10/15/2013 03:30 AM UTC
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here first I am getting the date object then again getting the date as string so now if I need a date object I again have to transfer this string to a date object. Am I correct? If yes, is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Not at all, we first set SimpleDateFormat - > configure time zone -> parse string date -> extract proper String date based on  DateFormat.

Comment: So now I have the date string in UTC. How can I transfer it to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormatInUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aaa z");
    System.out.println(new Date()); //prints local date-time
    outputFormatInUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(outputFormatInUTC.format(new Date())); //prints UTC date-time
```